# Regex Pattern match to find and replace

Tags: php, regex-negation

I am trying to create a regex pattern to find and then replace my IMG src tags in my HTML template.

Essentially, the pattern should find the contents of the src:

And then replace it as such:
none

In above code source is always same data-lazy-src is chnaging

Comment: Can you share your code? What have you tried?

Comment: <img src="http://cdn.iphonehacks.com/wp-content/plugins/lazy-load/images/1x1.trans.gif" data-lazy-src="http://cdn.iphonehacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/71cts8jvKRL._SL1500_.png" alt="anki-overdrive-supercars-racing-race-track-remote-control-ios" width="800" height="533">

Comment: Regex is not for such complex task. Use HTML parser library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll agree that regex isn't necesarily the right way to do this. Here is a solution using the HTML Dom parser:

```
  $html = 'your markup';
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($html);

  $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
  if(count($tags) > 0) {
       $tag = $tags->item(0);
       $tag->setAttribute('src', $new_src_url);
       $doc->saveHTML($tag);
  }
```

Then, `$doc` should have your updated markup with the src atributes of your images changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```php
preg_replace('/(<img.*) src=\"[^"]*\"(.*>)/', '$1 src="none"$2', $html)
```